# Result set has no current row

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

"result set has no current row" this error shows up for the first time only
and then when i reset the fields and enter the details again than this code works like a charm for each and every time until i close and run program again and i don't know why is this thing showing up only for the first tym i even made my username column primary key in the database i found this somewhere on internet but doesn't solves my problem

```
private void DoneBtnChangePassMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                               


        String db_username , db_pass;

        LogInGUI LG = new LogInGUI();
        LG.Connection();

        String usrname = UsernameFieldCP.getText();
        String CrntPass = CurrentPassFieldCP.getText();
        String newpassfield = NewPassFieldCp.getText();
        String repeatpassfield = RepeatPassFieldCP.getText();

           try
        {
            if(usrname.equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Fill The Fields !");
            }
            else{
                if (CrntPass.equals(newpassfield)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Hah! You Cant Enter The Same Password.");
                }
                else{
                    if(!newpassfield.equals(repeatpassfield)){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "New Password and Repeat Password Fields Does Not Match !");
                    }
                    else{

            LG.state = LG.conn.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT Username , Password FROM CreateUser WHERE Username = '"+usrname+"' AND Password = '"+CrntPass+"' ";
            LG.rs = LG.state.executeQuery(query);

            LG.rs.next();

                db_username = LG.rs.getString("Username");
                db_pass = LG.rs.getString("Password");

                if (db_username.equals(usrname) && db_pass.equals(CrntPass))
                {
                    if (newpassfield.equals(repeatpassfield))
                    {
                         LG.state = LG.conn.createStatement();
                         String query1 = "UPDATE CreateUser SET Password = '"+newpassfield+"' WHERE USERNAME = '"+usrname+"' ";
                         LG.state.execute(query1);

                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Password Changed");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "ReType New Password Correctly");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "InCorrect Username Or Password");
                }


                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: rs.next() might return false - you'll want to check with if for that...

Comment: As Jan already said, `rs.next()` probably returns false which means that the resultset is empty (ie, no rows will be returned). Also, you are leaving yourself open to SQL Injection attacks. Read more about SQL Injection Prevention [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: can you give me a piece of code for that ?

Comment: `if(!rs.next()) return; // no results, login failed`.

Comment: then how will i start the code again like i want to run the change pass code what should i do for that ?